# Syntax highlighting for .dryml in Notepad++

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notepad++, hobo

I've been learning Hobo, an awesome wrapper for Ruby on Rails that I'm finding extremely DRY and n00b-friendly.

But how do I set Notepad++ to automatically recognize .dryml files such that appropriate syntax highlighting is applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you're still looking at this question. Here's your answer: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Languages :)

Comment: So it hasn't been done before, and I'm the first one to have this need, and it's up to me to implement it. Okay, thanks for the answer!

Comment: As far as I've seen, you would be the first one. But at least you have reference for implementing it. More than welcome!